# Django memcached cache always response with 200 status code

Tags: python, django, http, caching, memcached

I want to use memcached for my REST API resource caching.

As I know When browser request resource of my API server, Etag and Last-Modified header is used for validation. and 304 code is returned if resource of cache server is valid.

I had set my settings.py in the way Django document explains to connect memcached. But 304 code didn't show. Always 200 code is returned.

When I check status through 'memcached -vv' command inside termianl, It looks like that the memcached is successfully running because 'set' 'get' is called.

I wonder I need more additional request header or this is the normal state.

Below is response header part that I tested with postman.
[image]

Below is the terminal window that I checked with 'memcached -vv' command.

[image]

Comment: Are you connecting to a local memcached server? I had similar issues with AWS and it turned out that the memcached server would only work with the production environment and I could not connect to it from my local dev env.

Comment: @WayBehind Yes! I'm now using my local memcached server.

Comment: @WayBehind 304 code was returned in your  production env?

Comment: Sorry, I cant recall what the status code was, only remember that I only had issues locally but everything worked OK on production servers.

Comment: @WayBehind Okay. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Did you find the reason?